# R Error: replacement has length zero - Help needed

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am using a loop function for the first time in R to run a number of calculations for numerous country polygons. I developed a working code using the following [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130522/increasing-speed-of-crop-mask-extract-raster-by-many-polygons-in-r).

I created a list of SpatialPolygonsDataFrames and my code seems to run well but stops after a certain number of countries, giving me the following error.

```
# Large list of 51 elements containing SPDFs
bound <- list(ARG, AUS, AUT, BEL, BGR, BRA, CAN, CHE, CHL, CHN, COL, CRI, CZE, DEU, DNK, ESP, EST, EU27, FIN, FRA, GBR, GRC, HRV, HUN, IDN, IND, IRL, ISL, ISR, ITA, JPN, KOR, LTU, LUX, LVA, MEX, NLD, NOR, NZL, PER, POL, PRT, ROU, RUS, SAU, SVK, SVN, SWE, TUR, USA, ZAF)

result <- data.frame() #empty result data frame

for (i in 1:51) { #this is the number of polygons to iterate through
  country <- bound[[i]] #selects a single polygon
  clip1 <- crop(population, extent(country))
  clip2 <- crop(wind, extent(country))
  cat1 <- calc(clip2, fun=function(x){ x[x > 1.1] <- NA; return(x)})
  clip4 <- mask(clip1, cat1)
  ext_cat1 <- cellStats(clip4, 'sum')
  tab <- lapply(ext_cat1, table)
  mat<- as.data.frame(tab)
  final <- cbind(country@data$iso3, mat) #combines into single data frame
  result <- rbind(final,result)
}
```

> Error in res[i] <- readBin(x@file@con, what = dtype, n = 1, size =
> dsize,  :    replacement has length zero In addition: There were 23
> warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Would anyone know what may be happening and what I can do to ensure it runs through all the country shapefiles in my list?

Comment: It is very difficult to help since you do not provide a self-contained (i.e. including the data) example. However, you should be able to figure this out yourself by checking what the value of `i` is when this breaks, and then you can sequentially run each line inside the loop and see where it fails. If you still do not understand why, at least it should help you focus and rewrite the question.  There are also a lot of warnings, what are they? The error message you get suggests that you may be out of (temp) disk space.

Comment: The problem is that these are large datasets. `population` is a global layer from the Joint Research Centre Global Human Settlement Layer [link] (https://ghsl.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ghs_pop2019.php), while `wind` is based on daily wind speed data from the Copernicus Climate Change Store [link] (https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/sis-agrometeorological-indicators?tab=overview). The code runs for a few countries and breaks once I run it on the all 51 countries shps. Also, when I type in `warnings()`, it does not show anything actually. Only the error as given above...

Comment: The idea is not to include the actual data, but to create some data with code. See the examples in the R packages help files.  But that might not help here as the the culprit is likely a corrupted file. Again, you can find out where it breaks, and then step through the lines and see where it fails, and then find out why or improve your question. "Something breaks in a loop" is just not sufficient as a question.